# Is it ok to store token and passwords in iOS keychain with iOS and Rails API app?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, jwt

I am building an iOS app with Rails backend.

For authentications, I am using rails gem called devise_token_auth.
https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

I am storing access-token, client-id, and email in iOS keychain after signup or login.

However, for security reason, the token should be expired in 2weeks, so iOS users should re-login every 2 weeks.

I guess, you can use refresh-token in this case, but I couldn't find refresh-token from devise_token_auth gem unfortunately.

So, in this case, is it ok to store user password in iOS keychain to re-login automatically when the token gets expired, or storing password in keychain is bad idea which should be avoid?

If it's not good practice to store password in keychain to avoid logging in every 2weeks from mobile app, is there any recommendation which refresh-token can be used with?

I am wondering if I can use refresh-token with this jwt gem.
https://github.com/nsarno/knock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing user credentials is a bad practice and should be avoided. It would defeat the point of trying to make the application more secure by expiring the token.

To avoid the common issue of expiring tokens in the middle of the application being used, you could implement sliding sessions. The idea is to send back a new short-lived token with every authenticated action made by the user. As long as the user is active he will stay authenticated.

The user would only be prompted for his credentials again after being inactive for longer than the expiration period (2 weeks in this case), which I believe makes sense.

You can also have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/nsarno/knock/issues/65) in knock, where sliding sessions and refresh tokens are being discussed.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really informative and it helped a lot!

Comment: What are some other methods besides sliding sessions? Or is this the most common method for API interaction with mobile apps?

Answer (score 6):

usually I would agree with @nsarno but in this case I don't. Yes, storing critical data on a device is bad practice and should always be avoided if possible. BUT the Keychain is build for this purpose. The password/token can only be accessed by your App (or intruders) if the device is unlocked (via Biometric Auth. or Pin).

Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services
All necessary functions are explained there.